# calibration of the BNO055 - how does it occurs?

Tags: imu

The 'internal calibration' in the Bosch IMU BNO055 ([datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST_BNO055_DS000_12.pdf)), says that the sensor will be calibrated everytime 'Power on Reset'. What does Power on Reset means?

Does it calibrates itself every time the device and the bn055 is turned on or will it need to be in special mode? Meaning that every time i turn on my sensor, if i want a proper accelerometer calibration value, i will need to turn the sensor to 6 different faces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means calibration data is volatile and you need to follow directions so that your device can find its way.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor/device-calibration

> To generate valid calibration data, the following criteria should be met:
>
> Gyroscope: The device must be standing still in any position
>   Magnetometer: In the past 'figure 8' motions were required in 3 dimensions, but with recent devices fast magnetic compensation takes place with sufficient normal movement of the device
>
> Accelerometer: The BNO055 must be placed in 6 standing positions for +X, -X, +Y, -Y, +Z and -Z.  This is the most onerous sensor to calibrate, but the best solution to generate the calibration data is to find a block of wood or similar object, and place the sensor on each of the 6 'faces' of the block, which will help to maintain sensor alignment during the calibration process.  You should still be able to get reasonable quality data from the BNO055, however, even if the accelerometer isn't entirely or perfectly calibrated.
>
> Persisting Calibration Data
>
> Once the device is calibrated, the calibration data will be kept until the BNO is powered off.
>
> The BNO doesn't contain any internal EEPROM, though, so you will need to perform a new calibration every time the device starts up, or manually restore previous calibration values yourself.

Comment: I understand that, but what I dont understand is will that occurs everytime the device is turned on? Or I should program the sensor in a special way so that they gather the data and the use the data as the calibration value?

Comment: " you will need to perform a new calibration every time the device starts up, or manually restore previous calibration values yourself."

Comment: great, I understand that. But how long is it usually takes to calibrate the sensor? So if I let say turn the device for a minute no and haven't rotate the sensor to 6 different faces, will it still calibrate once i do the movement?

Comment: depends on practise reading and following directions

Comment: One extra question I hope I can get answer to:

Comment: writeByte(byte(BNO055),byte(BNO055_OPR_MODE),byte(CONFIG_OPR_MODE));
writeByte(byte(BNO055),byte(BNO055_UNIT_SEL),byte(CHOSEN_UNIT));
writeByte(byte(BNO055),byte(AXIS_MAP_CONFIG),byte(STANDARD_AXIS));
writeByte(byte(BNO055),byte(BNO055_OPR_MODE),byte(NDOF_OPR_MODE));

I set the mode to config mode and after seeting the units and axis, I also set the mode to NDOF mode. Will it still run the calibration everytime I turn the sensor on? Or Do i need to wait for like a couple of minutes to do the calibration movement before setting it to NDOF mode? Can youu give example how to program this?